# Remove items from list not in 'speeches'?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, trim

```
url = 'http://www.millercenter.org/president/speeches'

conn = urllib2.urlopen(url)
html = conn.read()

miller_center_soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
links = miller_center_soup.find_all('a')

linklist = [tag.get('href') for tag in links if tag.get('href') is not None]
linklist = str(linklist)

end_of_links = [line for line in linklist if '/events/' in line]
print end_of_links
```

This is a tiny snippet of my output (saved in a Python list).

```
['/events/2015/one-nation-under-god-how-corporate-america-invented-christian-america', 
'/events/2015/a-conversation-with-bernie-sanders', '#reagan', '#gwbush', '#obama',
'#top', '/president/obama/speeches/speech-4427', president/obama/speeches/speech-4430', ...]
```

I want to delete all items in the list that do not contain `speeches`. I've tried `filter()` and just creating another list comprehension, but that hasn't yet worked. I don't know why the `end_of_links` variable is not working - it seems intuitive to me, at least.

Comment: if creating another list suits you: `[el for el in l if 'speeches' not in el]`

Comment: More apropros, do you mean `line for line in linklist if 'speeches' not in linklist`? This still gives me an empty list, after-the-fact.

Comment: `l` is your input list from which you need to remove elements which contain 'speeches'. I have no idea on which list you want to operate, since I cannot see 'speeches' in your code attempt.

Comment: You can also use `filter(lambda el: 'speeches' not in el, l)`

Comment: It's not clear from your question.. Are you saying you want only links from linklist where the link contains both '/events/' and 'speeches' ?

Comment: I want links from `linklist` where the link contains 'speeches'. I'm trying to remove all other ones. The way the website organizes all the speeches is like 'speeches/obama/speech-1' and 'speeches/kennedy/speech-1', etc.

Comment: then `l` is `linklist` in my comments above

Comment: I get this when I print that result: `[]`. Should I store `linklist` as string?

Comment: no. I think you should edit your question and clarify which list you want to operate on / the sample belongs to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

li = ['/events/2015/one-nation-under-god-how-corporate-america-invented-christian-america',
      '/events/2015/a-conversation-with-bernie-sanders', '#reagan', '#gwbush', '#obama',
'#top', '/president/obama/speeches/speech-4427', 'president/obama/speeches/speech-4430']

import re

li = [ x for x in li if re.search('speeches',x)]

print(li)

['/president/obama/speeches/speech-4427', 'president/obama/speeches/speech-4430']

Answer (score 0):

Kust keep the ones that *do* include 'speeches':

```
link_list = ['/events/2015/one-nation-under-god-how-corporate-america-invented-christian-america',
 '/events/2015/a-conversation-with-bernie-sanders', '#reagan', '#gwbush', '#obama',
 '#top', '/president/obama/speeches/speech-4427', 'president/obama/speeches/speech-4430']
speech_list = [_ for _ in link_list if 'speeches' in _]
```

Here is my terminal session, in Python2.7

```
>>> link_list = ['/events/2015/one-nation-under-god-how-corporate-america-invented-christian-america',
...  '/events/2015/a-conversation-with-bernie-sanders', '#reagan', '#gwbush', '#obama',
...  '#top', '/president/obama/speeches/speech-4427', 'president/obama/speeches/speech-4430']
>>> speech_list = [_ for _ in link_list if 'speeches' in _]
>>> speech_list
['/president/obama/speeches/speech-4427', 'president/obama/speeches/speech-4430']
>>>
```

Comment: I just get this printout when I run that: `[]`. Should I save `linklist` as `str`?

Comment: Did you print speech_list?  That's where the items are stored.

Comment: Yes. When I run all that code above and then run `speech_list = [_ for _ in linklist if 'speeches' in _] print speech_list`, I get `[]`